# Focus change after switch off camera?

Tags: focus, focal-length, camera-settings

I am using a zoom lens. The focal length is adjusted to 70 mm with manual focus.

I then switch off the camera. Will the focus change after i re-turn on the camera?

Noted that focal length and zoom ring remains unchanged from the beginning.

Comment: More information required, including a clearer question and title please.

Comment: Also camera model.

Comment: If you are already using it, why don't you just try and find it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the focus change after i re-turn on the camera?

Of the DSLRs that I can think of, none changes the focus setting when you turn the camera off or on. However, if you have the camera configured to focus with a half-press of the shutter release, the focus may change if you try to take a picture.

If you have the camera in your possession, it's easy enough to test: just keep an eye on the focus distance indicator on the lens as you turn the camera off and on again.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the focus change after i re-turn on the camera?

Yes, but only if you are using a Canon STM lens. STM lenses will rack the focus in, and then out, when you turn the camera on, but it should return to the original focus distance.

Non-STM lenses will not change focus.